# The Fock space in Costello's paper "Higher genus Gromov-Witten invariants as genus zero invariants of symmetric products"

Tags: gromov-witten-theory, orbifolds, symmetric-power

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. In this [Annals paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2006/164-2/p05), Costello expressed the descendent genus $g$ Gromov-Witten (GW) invariants of $X$ in terms of genus zero GW invariants of the symmetric product stack $S^{g+1}(X)$. In the introduction of the paper, he defined the Fock space as follows

$$ \text{Sym}^* \left( H^*(X, \mathbb{C} ) \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} t \mathbb{C}[t] \right) = \oplus_{d \geq0} H^*_{\text{orb}}\left( S^d(X),\mathbb{C}\right).$$

**Why is the LHS same as the RHS?**

What does the parameter $t$ in the LHS correspond to in the RHS? Also I'm not sure why it is $t \mathbb{C}[t]$ rather than $\mathbb{C}[t]$. An arbitrary element of order $k$ in the LHS has the form

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} a_{1j} t^j \cdots \sum_{j=1}^{n_k} a_{kj} t^j,$$

where $a_{ij} \in H^*(X, \mathbb{C} )$. Does this correspond to an element in $H^*_{\text{orb}}\left( S^k(X),\mathbb{C}\right)$ in the RHS? If everything is obvious, then it means I have a gap somewhere. I would appreciate it if someone could point that out for me.